# which data type in orient db for @rid?

Tags: java, spring, orientdb

i tried to fetch all data from orientdb using java.
my code is

```
    public static ArrayList<dbentity.DoctorEntity> viewAllDoctor(){
    graph = factory.getTx();
    ArrayList<dbentity.DoctorEntity> al=new ArrayList<dbentity.DoctorEntity>();
    for (Vertex v : graph.getVerticesOfClass("DoctorA")) {
        System.out.println(v.getProperty("@rid"));
        dbentity.DoctorEntity disent=new DoctorEntity(v.getProperty("@rid"), v.getProperty("NAME"),v.getProperty("specialization"));
        al.add(disent);
    }
    graph.shutdown();
    return al;
    }
```

i want add @rid to ArrayList but it showing error. I thing the problem with datatype
my DoctorEntity class is.

```
public class DoctorEntity {
private String name;
private String specialization;
private String rid;

public DoctorEntity(Object rid, Object name,Object specialization){
    this.name=(String) name;
    this.specialization=(String) specialization;
    this.rid=(String) rid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getSpecialization() {
    return specialization;
}
public String getRid() {
    return rid;
}}
```

error showing is
exception: "java.lang.ClassCastException"
message: "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast **Vertex** to **OrientVertex** and call **getIdentity().toString()**.
See [here](http://orientdb.com/javadoc/latest/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/impls/orient/OrientExtendedVertex.html#getIdentity--).

```
for (Vertex v : graph.getVerticesOfClass("DoctorA")) {
    OrientVertex vertex = (OrientVertex) v;
    dbentity.DoctorEntity disent = new DoctorEntity(vertex.getIdentity().toString(), v.getProperty("NAME"), v.getProperty("specialization"));
    al.add(disent);
}
```